# OpenSSL version file is not found or is not usable

Tags: openssl, ndnsim

I am trying to install ndnSIM. It requires some dependencies and one of them is OpenSSL.

I have already installed it with homebrew as

```
brew install openssl
```

but every time I try to ./waf configure ndnSIM,it returns an error such as

OpenSSL version file is not found or is not usable
(complete log in /Users/ndnSIM/ns-3/build/config.log)

and when I get into the config.log, the complete error shows also:

Checking for OpenSSL version
from /Users/ndnSIM/ns-3/src/ndnSIM: OpenSSL version file is present, but is not recognizable

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As of Sep 2021, the command `brew install openssl` installs OpenSSL 3.0 and ndnSIM is not yet compatible with that version of OpenSSL.

Try:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

to install OpenSSL 1.1.1 instead. You may need to uninstall any other versions of OpenSSL using `brew rm -f openssl` before installing `openssl@1.1`.

Alternatively, you can try applying [this patch](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx/commit/2b47ac0a6f736b34e679f8ef29260ffa3baef225) to the copy of ndn-cxx inside your local clone of ndnSIM.

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.